# How to keep the resolution of an image when scaling it in Gimp

Tags: gimp, resolution

I want to copy and paste one picture into another one using Gimp.

I have a picture with 200x200 pixels and 72dpi. The 72dpi are not enough to print the image in the size specified in its header. Therefore, I want to reduce it to half its printing size, but keep the 200x200 pixels to get to a 144dpi resolution.

Since the picture I'm pasting has rather low quality, I want to reduce its size within the other picture and at the same time increase the resolution (that is, keep the number of pixels constant).

However, the only option I found was the `Print Size` function, which does not seem to affect the size of the pasted image relative to the picture it is pasted into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After pasting the picture, you'll see that a new layer will be formed named *"Floating Selection"* Right click on it and then click on "New Layer".

Now it has become a layer. Again right click on that layer name and select "Scale Layer". Now you can scale this layer relative to the main Picture.

Lemme know if your problem is not solved. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While this method does allow to scale the number of pixels, I was wondering if I could keep the number of pixels but reduce the print size in order to enhance the resolution?

Comment: To make my question clearer, let me give an example: I have a picture with 200x200 pixels and 72dpi. The 72dpi are not enough to print the image in the size specified in its header. Therefore, I want to reduce it to half its printing size, but keep the 200x200 pixels to get to a 144dpi resolution. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot do this, its actually improving the quality of an image. One can scale down the quality but scaling up...? I'm sorry.

Comment: Well, I understand you cannot add information, but you can keep all the information (pixels) and reduce the size?

Answer (score 2):

ez. Image -> Scale Image -> Quality Interpolation = off -> change dpi from 72 to 144. glhf.

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean with "ez" and "glhf"? Please explain better what you mean and this can solve the given issue ...

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - Please look through [tour] to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query here, and how best to frame it. Please give a little more detail about how and why your proposed solution addresses all of OP's needs - thanks!

Comment: Further, I assume "...ez..." & "...glhf.." are: "easy" & "good luck, have fun". We *prefer* complete sentences and little use of slang to allow this response to be of value to future searchers and searchers now who may be operating in other than English, or even to help those who *are* operating in actual English but not age and social group specific vernacular such as this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Image -> Print Size dialog is the right choice - but you have to be aware that the PPI value of the image you are pasting **into** matters, not the value of the image you are pasting.

Comment: Print Size has its limitations, in fact you can't see the actual result on screen and if you print the image the only available formats are: PDF Postscript and SVG